# How to have Azure traffic manager infront of azure API management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-traffic-manager

How to implement Azure traffic management for Azure API management. I am confused with the implementation steps.

**What I've tried:**
Consider I have two API's in two regions.

1) http://xxxxx.azure-api.net/application1/service

2) http://xxxxx.azure-api.net/application2/service

So, how to implement.

First I created traffic management profile and got address like mysite.traffic-manager.net..  ,after that I have given DNS name(FQDN) as xxxxx.azure-api.net.

So, what is the next step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a DNS certificate for mysite.traffic-manager.net and use that to setup custom hostname - mysite.traffic-manager.net - on both APIM services. Setup TM too forward calls to XXX.azure-api.net and YYY.azure-api.net. Optionally setup health probes for /status-0123456789abcdef to monitor APIM status and take it out of rotation if service is down for some reason.

Or scale up to Premium tier and use multi-geo feature to add second region to single APIM service. Then all you need to do is setup custom hostname, TM will be created internally with performance profile. Although that is more expensive than having two basic/standard services with custom TM infront.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, how to get DNS certificate.

Comment: Well, you either have to create self-signed certificate just for dev time or go with full one. Checkout https://letsencrypt.org, for example, on how to obtain free SSL certificate.